# sort order for sizes like S,M,XL,..etc

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, sorting

I have various sizes for my configurable products to display it in order in product view page i used array_reverse for number 1,2,3 so now sizes with numbers are arranged in order.but how to do this in S,M,XL,XS..kindly help me

Comment: are you want to different sort order type for  different configuration

Comment: no same order for all products some static format like s,m,xl,xs app\code\community\OrganicInternet\SimpleConfigurableProducts\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable.php

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1.9.1 (1.14.1 EE) has a bug where it ignores the position data that Amit suggested. There is a PHP solution and I also have a temporary JS solution here: [Why are my attributes showing out of position order on Magento 1.9.1.0 frontend?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60145/why-are-my-attributes-showing-out-of-position-order-on-magento-1-9-1-0-frontend/60472)

Answer (score 0):

Magento is managed this sort by from `attribute option field position` if you change this sort order  from here then it is automatically change dropdown sort order at frontend

[image]

This setting you need to go at `admin>Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > [Your Attribute] > Manage Label / Options`

Answer (score 0):

Although this may not be the exact answer to your situation one of the possibilities might be that the sort order of the attributes are set incorrectly on the configurable product level.  If you look under the Associate Products tab for the configurable product check to see that the order is correct.  If it is incorrect you will have to recreate the configurable product.