# Why are my attributes showing out of position order on Magento 1.9.1.0 frontend?

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, frontend

The size attribute options on my configurable products are not displaying in the correct position on the frontend. They are displaying in the order of product ID instead

I have set the position on the size attribute in the admin panel (i.e. XS is position 1, S is position 2), but this appears to be disregarded on shop frontend.  I've already reindexed and flushed all caches.

Is this a known error? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meogi has a great fix for this here:
[Magento 1.9.1 configurable product attribute sorting](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45396/magento-1-9-1-configurable-product-attribute-sorting?rq=1)

Unfortunately I'm using Amasty Color Swatches Pro and that breaks it so I had to come up with another solution.

For now, I am re-sorting the getJsonConfig() object in my configurable.phtml template for the hard-coded size attribute (175):

```
$attribs = json_decode($this->getJsonConfig());
if($attribs->attributes)
{
    foreach($attribs->attributes as $attr)
    {
        if($attr->id == 175) //re-sort size
            {
                usort($attr->options, function ($a, $b){
                $sortOrder = Array("one size","petite","x-small","small","medium","large","x-large","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31");
                return (array_search($a->label, $sortOrder) > array_search($b->label, $sortOrder)) ? 1 : -1;
                });
            }
    }
}
$attribs_json = json_encode($attribs);
```

And then in my JS, I'm calling this:

```
var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $attribs_json; ?>);
```

instead of

```
var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
```